# ControlTemplate makes TextBox content disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to apply a style to my `TextBox` so I added a style in a `ResourceDictionary`. But when it comes to the `ControlTemplate` it makes my TextBoxes break. When I remove the `<ControlTemplate>` block the TextBoxes work again.

Do anyone know how to apply my ControlTemplate to my textbox style?

I'm totally new to resource dictionaries for `xaml` elements so I have no idea how to solve this issue...

P.S: in the same file I have another style for my buttons is that okay ? Or do I need to create separate files for each style?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Gotham Light"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- #region this is where the code doesn't work -->
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="White">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <!-- #endregion -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#96c80a"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are telling the ControlTemplate to show a blank `TextBlock`.  Take a look at the [default ControlTemplate for a TextBox online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), and  you will see that in order to show the textbox, you need to label a ScrollViewer inside of your ControlTemplate with the hardcoded Name "PART_ContentHost".

Change your ControlTemplate to be this and it will work again:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5"
    BorderThickness="5"
    BorderBrush="Black">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```